# How to check nearby any road is there or not by using lat/long values in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing Gps tracker application android, and i am trying to track the bus route and show it in google map, i am getting latitude and longitude value of bus location even bus is moving or not moving also.

My problem:-
Bus is moving on the road and i am getting lat/long values and throw it in my google map. the problem is My marker is moving on building,river also even bus is going  on the road

My requirement:-
My marker should move only on the road not on building
Suppose if my lat/long values is off the road(outside road) it should check near by any road is there or not if it is there My marker has to locate on the road

How to check nearby any road is there or not by using lat/long values

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/) that has a [Snap to Road](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) feature. They have a [sample app for Android](https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples) that explains how to use it. Specifically, see [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/maps/roadsapi/MainActivity.java) file from the project.

Other than that, you need an extra key beyond the normal Google Maps one.

> This app requires two keys before it will run, one for the Google Maps API for Android and one for the Roads API.
>
> To obtain a Google Maps API for Android key, follow the instructions in the API's Getting Started guide and add it to the google_maps_key field in app/src/debug/res/values/api_keys.xml.
>
> To obtain a Roads API key, follow the instructions in the API key section of the Roads docs and add it to the google_maps_web_services_key field in app/src/debug/res/values/api_keys.xml.

And an extra import for your project

`compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'`